# Creating a gradient of an image per color

Tags: c#, .net, image-processing, gradient, radial-gradients

This question is intended to gather some preliminary information and options on how to solve this problem without reinventing the wheel.

I work on a piece of software that receives 8-bit images from a camera like device. The image obtained is single color (again, 8-bit), and then we color the image according to a 16 colors colormap we have. Let's say for example a 'Jet' colormap:
[image]

I am being tasked with creating a gradient colormap.
This means within each blob of color bin, I need to create a gradient in the transparency (alpha values) from the outline of the blob to the center of it. 
here's an example:

[image]

This design was given to me by a designer, and he used some sort of a graphic design software to generate it.

Another consideration is that the algorithm I will use should be able to do that in ~50ms to satisfy real-time requirements. But I can worry about it later.

I am looking for a library, or algorithm that can do something like this. I have an algorithm in mind that could work, but I think optimization and debugging for robustness would take a long time. 
This will need to be integrated into a .NET project, probably in C#. 
I am not looking to reinvent the wheel if I don't have to. Any help would be appreciated.

so far I found ['gradients made easy'](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20018/Gradients-made-easy) project that can perform a gradient for a given shape. 
it's a step in the right direction, but not quite what I am looking for.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can do each color in a different layer, an inverse of a gaussian blur could generate the transparency for each layer. It would be a slow process overall though.

Comment: A very naive and slow implementation could be: first you'll need to use an algorithm such as k-means clustering to posterize the colors in the input image to the number of layers you want. Then, for each layer, you need to go over each pixel that isn't empty and find the distance to the closest edge, and use that as the alpha value. Then composite all the layers one on top of the other. Depending on the resolution, that might be a challenge for c# to do in 50ms, but you could probably have a prototype working within a day.

Comment: You won't get exactly the output though, because you don't really have any layer data, you only have a height map. The graphic designer is cheating in a way, they are making assumptions about the shapes of the layers we don't see.

Comment: @Rotem, thanks! 
getting the layers is easy enough. In order to get a layer info, all data below the color-bin cutoff value is 0, and everything above is 1. 
Then the challenge is to perform blob analysis to determine an enclosed region. Once we have that, we can find the geometric center of each blob, and from there the road to gradient is pretty straight forward.